# How to make jQuery Datatable pagination to neglect hidden rows?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with some hidden rows. Now, when I use jQuery datatable plugin with bootstrap pagination, it takes into account all the rows. Say if I have 100 rows (50 hidden) and display 10 rows per page, currently there will be 10 pages while the desired result is to have only 5 pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Data Tables community I learnt that the above is not natively supported as the plugin treats all rows equally. However the desired effect can be achieved using range filtering. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html